# Can we copy entire master DB from staging to Dev using sitecore Powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am curious to know any such commands or way to copy master DB from one sitecore environment to another ?

I have a clue of using Copy-Item however I don't have much idea on that.

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation? For this to work the database would need to be attached to the same instance; otherwise you would need to use something like the SPE Remoting to communicate with another instance. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

Comment: Why you need to use SPE for this?